Volume element in QFT
The Hamiltonian of a free scalar field in QFT is given by:
$$\hat{H} = \int{\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{8\pi^3}\hbar\omega_k\left(\hat{n}_k + 4\pi^3\delta^{(3)}(0)\right)}.$$
And $\hat{n}_k = \hat{a}^\dagger_ka_k$. From Tong's lecture, we can identify $8\pi^3\delta^{(3)}(0)$ with volume $\mathcal{V}$, so in practice the integral becomes:
$$\hat{H} = \int{\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{8\pi^3}\hbar\omega_k\left(\hat{n}_k + \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{V}\right)}.$$
The doubt comes from the $\hat{n}_k$ term. Is it not multiplied by volume? Does that mean that the general energy density is this?
$$\langle\rho\rangle = \frac{\langle n_k|\hat{H}|n_k \rangle}{\mathcal{V}} = \int{\frac{\mathrm{d}^3k}{8\pi^3}\hbar\omega_k\left(\frac{1}{\mathcal{V}}n_k + \frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
I know this is kind of a silly/basic question, but in absolutely every textbook I've seen they focus on the zero-point energy and omit the Dirac delta. Thus, I think the $n_k$ term should be divided by the volume, but as I have seen no one do that I am looking for confirmation here.

If the state $|n_k\rangle$ has a finite number of particles then its energy is finite. Then the energy density that you'll get by dividing by an infinite volume would be zero. Such a result is not really useful. So I guess it is not clear where you want to go with this?

I’m not sure what conventions you are using, but when you make these volumes explicit (which is actually necessary if you want things to work out dimensionally, e.g. to get a dimensionless S matrix, etc), the momentum integrals come with a factor of V in the numerator: $\sum_k \rightarrow V \int d^3k/(2\pi)^3$. This is because when transitioning from QM to QFT the summation symbol should become a dimensionless momentum integral. Check Landau and Lifshitz QFT volume, they keep the Vs explicit, whereas most QFT books implicitly set V=1 because it cancels out of observables.

@Wakabaloola great comment. I have seen the conversion from discrete to continuous but then in Tong’s lecture he did not include V into the integral. That was confusing me. So in reality you should add V to both terms, $1/2$ and $n_k$?
